# want to logout when clicked on logout button but its not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Actually the thing is I want to add function to my log out button.I tried but its not happening .So I have added my xml code below And also my java file corresponding.Any help is highly appreciated.

This is my my_snap_fragment.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AccountFragment"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="339dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="465dp"
        android:text="    QUOTE OF THE DAY"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="272dp"
        android:text="-She decided to start living
                               the life she imagined-"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkRed"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:background="@color/Pink"
        android:text="LOG OUT"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my AccountFragment.java file

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {



    public AccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    }
}
```

this is my loginpage.java file

```
public class loginpage extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username;
    EditText passwordd;
    Button login, signnow;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordd);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        signnow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signnow);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordd = findViewById(R.id.passwordd);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);

        Button signnow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signnow);
        signnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent p = new Intent(loginpage.this,new_user_register.class);
                startActivity(p);

            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String userrname = username.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordd.getText().toString();


                if (userrname.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PLEASE ENTER USERNAME AND PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                } else if (userrname.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ENTER USERNAME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();


                } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ENTER PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                } else if (!(userrname.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty())){
                    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userrname,password).addOnCompleteListener(loginpage.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                            }
                            else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(loginpage.this,bottom_nav.class));
                            }

                        }
                    });


                }else {

                    Intent i = new Intent(loginpage.this, bottom_nav.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
        

    }
}
```

this is my loginpage.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".loginpage"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="549dp"
        android:text="USER LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="450dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_foreground"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="393dp"
        android:hint="ENTER USERNAME" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="211dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="330dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_foreground"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordd"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="273dp"
        android:hint="ENTER PASSWORD" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="163dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="525dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imaagee" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="408dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="292dp"
        android:src="@drawable/iimagee" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagee" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imageee" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signnow"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="143dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="SIGN IN NOW"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add more details.

Comment: What more is needed???

Comment: I just want to write code for logout button ...I guess I have provided suficient code ..

Comment: Ihave added more code to make it transparent